# Assign a value to every object in an array without loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm adding a simple commenting component to angular 1 application. The object I get from the server looks like this:

```
comments":[
        {"id":1,"content":"this is my first comment","approved":1,"replies":[]},
        {"id":2,"content":"this is the second","approved":1,"replies":[
          {"priority_id":0,"content":"content of a reply","approved":1},
          {"priority_id":0,"content":"content of a second reply","approved":1}]
        }
      ]
```

At the moment I'm using 2 loops in the controller to assign a "pending" value to each comment and reply having approved:0

It looks like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.comments, function (comment) {
          if (comment.approved === 0) {
            comment.pending = true;
        }
          comment.replies = comment.replies || [];

          angular.forEach(comment.replies, function (reply) {
          if (reply.approved === 0) {
            reply.pending = true;
            }
          });
      });
```

Is there a better, shorter way to obtain that? Javascript is not exactly my forte. Do I really need to loop in the controller? Maybe I can somehow pass the value from ng-repeat? Thanks in advance!

Thanks to [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7090457/joe-hartzell) I got to know a better way than looping. I have marked his answer as the solution although I had to modify the code a bit to work because my application uses angular 1.4 which is incompatible with arrow functions. Here's the code:

```
$scope.comments.map(function(comment) {

                  if (comment.approved === 0) {
                    comment.pending = true;
                  }

                  comment.replies = comment.replies || [];

                  comment.replies.map(function(reply){
                     if (reply.approved === 0) {
                    reply.pending = true;
                    }
                    return reply.approved;
                  });
                  return comment.approved;

                });
```

It does not look as neat as Joe's but it still uses map method which, as suggested by Joe and Matthew, is better than looping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So not sure if this is more clear or just more condensed, but you could take advantage of the javascript .map prototype on arrays. What the map function does is iterates over an array and transforms each value to a new value depending on the function provided. So this would actually return a new array of objects mapped from the previous array. I'm not sure if this is really simpler. You could also take advantage of ES5 arrow functions.

One other thing: 
In your current code, a comment only gets a pending field if approved === 0. This means that if is not equal to 0, the pending field will not exist on the comment. This could lead to weird things later on if you are relying on this field. Some would say pending equals true, while other comments would be undefined. This is also true for your replies. My solution below uses the condition AS the pending field, so that it exists on every object, not just the true ones.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
$scope.comments.map(comment => {
    comment.pending = comment.approved === 0;
    comment.replies = (comment.replies || []).map(reply => {
        reply.pending = reply.approved === 0;
        return reply;
    });
    return comment;
})
```

Comment: shortened code using functions such as map typically make a function more terse and easier to read. I've upvoted.

Comment: That's what I thought, but wasn't sure if the OP wanted less code or no loops. Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which add that key to your objects. With this function, your loops will be like this:

```js
let comments = [{
  "id": 1,
  "content": "this is my first comment",
  "approved": 1,
  "replies": []
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "content": "this is the second",
  "approved": 1,
  "replies": [{
      "priority_id": 0,
      "content": "content of a reply",
      "approved": 1
    },
    {
      "priority_id": 0,
      "content": "content of a second reply",
      "approved": 1
    }
  ]
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "content": "this is the third",
  "approved": 0,
  "replies": [{
      "priority_id": 0,
      "content": "content of a reply",
      "approved": 0
    },
    {
      "priority_id": 0,
      "content": "content of a second reply",
      "approved": 0
    }
  ]
}];

function AddPending(obj) {
  obj['pending'] = true;
  return obj;
}

comments.forEach(function(comment) {

  comment = (comment.hasOwnProperty('approved') && comment.approved === 0) ? AddPending(comment) : comment;


  comment.replies = comment.replies || [];

  comment.replies.forEach(function(reply) {
    reply = (reply.approved === 0) ? AddPending(reply) : reply;
  });
});

console.log(comments);
```

Also you can upgrade this function which receives an object and checks the condition and if the condition is true, add the key. Use this function on `ng-repeat`. like below

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.comments = [{
    "id": 1,
    "content": "this is my first comment",
    "approved": 1,
    "replies": []
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "content": "this is the second",
    "approved": 1,
    "replies": [{
        "priority_id": 0,
        "content": "content of a reply",
        "approved": 1
      },
      {
        "priority_id": 0,
        "content": "content of a second reply",
        "approved": 1
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "content": "this is the third",
    "approved": 0,
    "replies": [{
        "priority_id": 0,
        "content": "content of a reply",
        "approved": 0
      },
      {
        "priority_id": 0,
        "content": "content of a second reply",
        "approved": 0
      }
    ]
  }];

  function AddPending(obj) {
    obj['pending'] = true;
    return obj;
  }

  $scope.f = function(comment) {
    comment = (comment.approved === 0) ? AddPending(comment) : comment;
    comment.replies = comment.replies || [];

    angular.forEach(comment.replies, function(reply) {
      reply = (reply.approved === 0) ? AddPending(reply) : reply;
    });
    return comment;
  };

});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <hr>
    <div ng-repeat="comment in comments track by $index">
      comment: {{f(comment)}}
      <hr>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```